# Effect of gate voltage on conductivity

Tags: electric-current, electronic-band-theory

I have this formula for the current based on conductivity but I cannot see the influence of the gate voltage. What does it change ? Is it the value of the conductivity that must be shifted as the potential barrier of the channel is shifted ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A gate voltage adds to the Fermi energy.

Comment: It adds to the Fermi level of the channel right ? which is equal to the fermi level of the source ?